# Task id in the yaml format

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Have you managed to create Task Group in the yaml format? Azure DevOps asks me to attach yaml format file when I'm trying to create a new task group in the web interface `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_taskgroups`.

I'd like to add a new task group but its format does not correspond to the build yaml format.
I have build with two tasks defined:

```
steps:
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive yml'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: yml
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).yml.zip'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

Its purpose is to archive and publish files to be used in the release later.

I converted those two steps to the task group (like it is [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/task-groups?view=azure-devops)) and it is exported as yaml like below (it exports json but it was converted to yaml):

```
tasks:
- environment: {}
  displayName: Archive yml
  alwaysRun: false
  continueOnError: false
  condition: succeeded()
  enabled: true
  timeoutInMinutes: 0
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: yml
    includeRootFolder: 'false'
    archiveType: zip
    tarCompression: gz
    archiveFile: "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).yml.zip"
    replaceExistingArchive: 'true'
    verbose: 'false'
    quiet: 'false'
  task:
    id: d8b84976-e99a-4b86-b885-4849694435b0
    versionSpec: 2.*
    definitionType: task
- environment: {}
  displayName: Publish Artifact
  alwaysRun: true
  continueOnError: false
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  enabled: true
  timeoutInMinutes: 0
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: "$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"
    ArtifactName: drop
    ArtifactType: Container
    TargetPath: "\\\\my\\share\\$(Build.DefinitionName)\\$(Build.BuildNumber)"
    Parallel: 'false'
    ParallelCount: '8'
  task:
    id: 2ff763a7-ce83-4e1f-bc89-0ae63477cebe
    versionSpec: 1.*
    definitionType: task
```

it looks fine and I can use it to compose yaml format definition for a new tasks but the problem is that task group uses Guid constant to identify what kind of task is it. Build task `- task: ArchiveFiles@2` are shown in the task group like:

```
task:
    id: d8b84976-e99a-4b86-b885-4849694435b0
```

How can I know what is a guid for any other kind of task?
`d8b84976-e99a-4b86-b885-4849694435b0` is a special constant value that is defined in the [git repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks) but it looks a little bit messy.

Is there any way to specify task using `ArchiveFiles@2` in the Task Group yaml format?

Comment: additionally I've found that it is not possible to export old (web-based) task that uses task group to the yaml code. Error message is shown `Task group has not been exported, task groups are not supported yet`. I'm afraid that it is not possible to use Task group from the yaml-based build pipeline.